# R: grouped data table with proportions

Tags: r, statistics

I have copied my code below. I start with a list of 50 small integers, representing the number of televisions owned by 50 families. My objective is shown in the object 'tv.final' below. My effort seems very wordy and inefficient.

Question: is there a better way to start with a list of 50 integers and end with a grouped data table with proportions? (Just taking my first baby steps with R, sorry for such a stupid question, but inquiring minds want to know.)

```
tv.data <- read.table("Tb02-08.txt",header=TRUE)
str(tv.data)
# 'data.frame':   50 obs. of  1 variable:
#  $ TVs: int  1 1 1 2 6 3 3 4 2 4 ...

tv.table <- table(tv.data)
tv.table
# tv.data
#  0  1  2  3  4  5  6 
#  1 16 14 12  3  2  2 

tv.prop <- prop.table(tv.table)*100
tv.prop
# tv.data
#  0  1  2  3  4  5  6 
#  2 32 28 24  6  4  4 

tvs <- rbind(tv.table,tv.prop)
tvs
#          0  1  2  3 4 5 6
# tv.table 1 16 14 12 3 2 2
# tv.prop  2 32 28 24 6 4 4

tv.final <- t(tvs)
tv.final
#   tv.table tv.prop
# 0        1       2
# 1       16      32
# 2       14      28
# 3       12      24
# 4        3       6
# 5        2       4
# 6        2       4
```

Comment: There's nothing really wrong with your code. You could skip the final step by using `cbind` instead of `rbind`. You could do it all within `with` too: `with(tv.data, { tv.table <- table(TVs); cbind(tv.table, tv.prop = prop.table(tv.table)*100) })`.

Answer (score 0):

You can treat the object returned by `table()` as any other vector/matrix:

```
tv.table <- table(tv.data)
round(100 * tv.table/sum(tv.table))
```

That will give you the proportions in rounded percentage points.